# vba run method when i close the sorting/filtiring mode and return to the regular mode of the file without filtiring

Tags: excel, vba

hello I want to run method when I close the sorting/filtiring mode and return to the regular mode of the Excel file without filtiring ... 
can I do that? ...

Comment: There is no event that triggers when you remove a filter or sort. Therefore you cannot.

Comment: but i want to run a function when i close the filtiring mode and return to the regular screen ... i want to reset caculation of all the cells of the page ..

Comment: Well, you can "want" this but the event doesn't magically appear just because of wanting it. If there is no event for that then there is no event for that. You can create a button for it. But there is no event to run code if you exit/remove a filter.

Comment: ok thanks , now if I want to calculate all the rows in my worksheet not just the visible rows when I been in the sorting mode . how can I do that ? this thing solve my problem too

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"calculate all the rows"* you need to be much more precise than that *"calculate"* can mean anything. Also if you ask a question it has to be in the question part, so we can write an answer to that. Make sure you ask one precise question in the original post that users can answer. Reading [ask] might help to improve your question. Including what you have tried so far or examples (see [mcve]) increase the probability of getting a good answer a lot.